# How to continue to statement2 while processing errors from statement1 with window.onerror

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I use `window.onerror(message,url,line)` to log my error messages because it gives me more debug information than `try{}catch(e){}`.

However, consider the following:

```
function1(); // Generates error
function2(); // Will not be executed
```

How can I ensure that function2 *will* fire while still using window.onerror?

Comment: Hi, just updated my js fiddle, so that you get the url and line numbers like you wanted when using a try-catch block, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I've found a way using `setTimeout`, but I hope there might be a better way:

```
setTimeout(function1);
setTimeout(function2);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7y2Ej/1/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. If you need error handling that allows later code to execute anyway you **must** use try..catch.

Luckily JavaScript does not have anything equivalent to VB6's `On Error Resume Next`; it would make lots of the bad JavaScript code out there much worse.

Comment: So is there a way to use try...catch in combination with window.onerror? I have two pieces of javascript example code on my site which I want to run. Both contain an error, which I catch and show alongside the code. How can I run both pieces of code?

Comment: When catching an error it will not trigger the global onerror handler. So nope, you cannot combine these. Why do you expect your code to fail in a way where the exception itself is not sufficient though?

Comment: I want to know the lineNumber where the code fails. The Error object does not give that away easily.

Answer (score 1):

made a fork of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sBw6u/1/), all I did was trigger the window.onerror event explicitly with the caught error.

Seems almost to good to be true :)

```
try
{
    function2();
}
catch(error)
{
    window.onerror(error);
}
```

​

**UPDATE**

Found a way to get the line number and url all the same. The code is a bit messy at the moment, but working, so it should get you started...

```
try
{
    function1();
}
catch(error)
{
    var url = error.stack.split('\n')[1].match(/\(.+\)/g)[0];
    var line = url.match(/\/\:[0-9]+.+$/g)[0];
    url = url.replace('(','').replace(line,'');
    line = line.replace(')','').replace('/:','')
    window.onerror(error,url,line);
}
```

and [Here is the working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBw6u/4/)

Comment: It *is* to good to be true ;) This way, you fill 'message' of window.onerror, but leave url and line undefined. See http://jsfiddle.net/sBw6u/2/. It is both 'message' and 'line' that I want to be filled. Still upvote for thinking along :)

Comment: I knew there had to be a catch :)

Comment: error.stack is not defined in IE, so this will not work cross-browser... Other than that: works well in Chrome! In Firefox, only the first function is executed...

Comment: I thougt there might be some issues with IE... [check this](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) article out, it's a very good cross browser stack tracer

Comment: I know that one. It checks the caller recursively to get the Stack Trace. The only thing that misses in IE... is the linenumber :-)

Comment: yup, I'm afraid MS doesn't like people writing code that actually provides useful information to users :-)